# More or less equal overloads

Tags: c#, overloading

The following code compiles in C# 4.0:

```
void Foo(params string[] parameters) { }
void Foo(string firstParameter, params string[] parameters) { }
```

How does the compiler know which overload you're calling? And if it can't, why does the code still compile?

Comment: +1, interesting question, though it's probably already answered in the specs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is well specified in the C# Language Specification, chapter 7.4.3.2, "Better function member":

*Otherwise, if MP is applicable in its normal form and MQ has a params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then MP is better than MQ*

*Otherwise, if MP has fewer declared parameters than MQ, then MP is better than MQ. This can occur if both methods have params arrays and are applicable only in their expanded forms.*

Fwiw, the C# Language Specification is a *very* readable document and can help you resolve these puzzles by yourself.  You have it on your machine, find it back in the Visual Studio install directory (like c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0) in the vc#\specifications\1033 subdirectory.

Another good one is the Ecma-335 standard document, freely available as a [PDF download](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).  It specifies the behavior of the CLR and the JIT compiler, great material to understand why C# (and the CLR) do what they do.  Recommended.

Comment: Interesting. If I take the OP code and call `Foo("one")` the compiler selects the second method (vs2010, .net 4), which seems wrong according to that quote. The only way that I managed to invoke the first method was to pass a string array as the only argument.

Comment: @Fredrik: my mistake, missed a rule.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the spec but I don't ever really think about it (if you know what I mean). When I have some time I will look at it so I don't look stupid asking this kind of questions ;-)

Comment: @Jouke, the upvotes you got puts you well past the "dumb question" threshold.  OT: how did you end up with a Frisian first name and a river in the South as a last name?

Answer (score 6):

In some cases, [it will decide for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). So, you might want to use different names in cases like this (or in more useful cases :-) ).

In particular, out of the four cases:

```
        Foo("bar");
        Foo("bar", "bar");
        Foo(new string[]{"bar", "bar"});
        Foo("bar", new string[] { "bar", "bar" });
```

only #1 and #2 are 'ambiguous' (since #3 and #4 naturally match overload 1 and 2 respectively).

In cases #1 and #2 overload resolution chooses overload #2, because it has a standalone string parameter that matches the only/first parameter of the invocation.

Comment: Oh yes, it does makes sense. I meant it's not very useful to have such 2 overloads.